# What is the best way to show the concept of $E$-$k$ diagram, indirect band gap, and effective mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I have read many articles about quantum mechanics but don't understand many of them because I'm not from physics. In addition, explanations on topics are not connected and quantum mechanical terms are used to explain quantum mechanical terms. I summarized couple of concepts about $E$-$k$ diagram, indirect band gap, and effective mass and drew the following illustrations.

I assumed $s$-orbital and $p$-like-orbital from atoms make lower and upper band of a crystal. Electron's wave function is solved and represented as a wave packet in the crystal. More overlap between orbitals leads to less energy required for electron to transit.

Could you comment or correct them?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]